# SQL WHERE/HAVING Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Currently I'm working in a forecasting project to estimate cash flow. This how the SQL query looks like:

```
SELECT [Date] AS ds, SUM([Sales Amount]) AS y, [Item ID]
FROM dbo.[Table]
GROUP BY [Date], [Item ID]
ORDER BY ds;
```

And in order to forecast sales I use an R package that strictly request that there has to be at least 2 instances where the forecast value(Sales) appears.

However there some instances in my query where an item it has been transacted just once.

Could you help me with an `HAVING` or `WHERE` condition where excludes all the items that were transacted just once?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a count and use that:

```
SELECT ds, y, [Item ID]
FROM (SELECT [Date] AS ds, SUM([Sales Amount]) AS y, [Item ID],
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [Item ID]) as cnt
      FROM dbo.[Table]
      GROUP BY [Date], [Item ID]
     ) t
WHERE cnt >= 2
ORDER BY ds;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is it possible to add another layer, in this case Location? Making the problem to have at least to 2 data sales point for every combination of item and location?

Comment: @J-Saw . . . Please ask *new* question with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Comment: Understood. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extra filtering condition in a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
  [Date] AS ds
 ,SUM([Sales Amount]) AS y
 ,[Item ID]
FROM dbo.[Table]
WHERE [Item ID] in ( -- filters out the items with less than 2 samples
  select distinct [Item ID] 
  from dbo.[Table] 
  group by [Item ID], [Date] having count(*) > 1
)
GROUP BY [Date]
        ,[Item ID]
ORDER BY ds
```